# Software Centre wont install or remove

Tags: software-center, dpkg

Ubuntu Software centre wont install or remove software with the following error message

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
reading files list for package 'gsfonts': Input/output error
Error in function:
```

I have tried uninstalling gsfonts through the software centre but no joy.

Any suggestions? I still cannot update or install/uninstall any software